# Java - How to connect to Microsoft Office 365 SharePoint

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, office365

I need to connect through our corporate firewall, into our SharePoint 2010 instance on Office 365.  I tried using [java-sharepoint-library](https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/):

```
NtlmAuthenticator credentials = new NtlmAuthenticator(
    "myactivedirectorydomain", "myusername", "mypassword"); 

HttpProxy httpProxy = new HttpProxy("proxy.ourcompany.com", 80);

SPSite site = new SPSite(
    new URL("https://ourcompany.com/sites/teams_MySandbox"), 
    credentials, 
    httpProxy, 
    true, 
    SPVersion.SP2010);

SPWeb rootWeb = site.getRootWeb(); //gives error below
```

Here is the error I get: "Server redirected too many  times (20)"

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getWeb(Unknown Source)
    at org.korecky.sharepoint.SPSite.getRootWeb(SPSite.java:280)
    at com.dupont.cintell.test4.TestSharePointConnection.testConnect(TestSharePointConnection.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    ... 44 more
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but i think you are hitting the Sharepoint Loopback check problem:

http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2010/05/24/sharepoint-disable-loopback-check-disableloopbackcheck-dword-in-registry/

Try one of the workaround, be conscious of the security problems involved on turning it off.

I would disable it temporarily just to check if it is indeed the problem.

Comment: Thanks but the server is in the Microsoft Office 365 cloud.  I cannot make registry changes on that server.  It should be possible to communicate with such a server using Java, since I am able to communicate with the server using MS Office clients (Access, Excel).

Comment: What proxy are you using? NTLM does not like proxies too much, do you have a keep alive property that you can set on the java client?

Comment: check if this is related: http://www.coderanch.com/t/473115/Web-Services/java/services-work-NTLM-Authentication-HTTPS

Comment: Hey thanks I am using regular Java HTTP/HTTPS proxy.

Comment: This recent post looks helpful: http://blog.ashwani.co.in/blog/2013-07-28/connect-and-access-sharepoint-webservice-from-java/  Looks like java-sharepoint-library is unreliable.  Will try that approach.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, is this solved? I am also facing the problem to connect to SP2013 and using the same code. Can you please help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried disabling the loopback address temporarily and see if that fixes it?